# Why can't I install pycoral~=2.0 (Error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement...)

Tags: windows-10, google-coral

I have installed a Coral M.2 accelerator into the M.2 wifi slot on my HP G2 SFF but I get an error when I try to install the pycoral library (but i suppose the error could be in my physical installation of the actual Module).

I've installed python 3.9.13 from the python website but when I run the command i get this error:

```
C:\Users\seth>python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral~=2.0
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycoral~=2.0 (from versions: 0.0.4, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.1.0, 0.2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycoral~=2.0
```

I also get an error when I try to install from the wheel file:

```
C:\Users\seth>python3 -m pip install https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/releases/download/v2.0.0/pycoral-2.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: pycoral-2.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Errors seem to imply that I either have not installed my coral module correctly or something in my system isn't compatible but it seems like i meet all the requirements

```
C:\Users\seth>python
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I expected this to work without error, any help would be greatly appreciated